# Prevent drag drop on child nodes of DotNetBar AdvTree/TreeControl

Tags: c#, treecontrol, dotnetbar

I'm implementing a TreeControl using the DotNetBar Advtree component.  However I seem to be struggling to find the property to make it impossible for a particular node to have any children.  What I want to stop the following below;

[image: How to stop this with the TreeControl component?]

For example an RSS feed cannot be contained with an RSS feed.  Some in effect I want some nodes to be draggable, and can have children, and others only draggable.

[image]

Thanks for any help.  I've noticed the property NodesIndent which I've setting to -1, or 5000 but neither was any help.

Comment: The docs that atkon link seem to suggest that you would subscribe to NodeDragFeedback event or BeforeNodeDrop event and cancel the action If it's an invalid location

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm struggling with.  I have different node types for each node on the tree, comparing them works fine with NodeDragFeedback but I can't reorder the nodes to wanted to find a different way; stopping a node from having children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just spotted in the documentation;

“Gets or sets the new insert position inside of NewParentNode.Nodes collection for the node being dragged. If InsertPosition is -1 the ParentNode refers to the current mouse over node and drag & drop node will be added as child node to it.”

So basically I can capture whether or not it is being added to as child node, compare the node type and decide whether to accept the drop.

Answer (score 2):

According to http://www.devcomponents.com/kb2/?p=327, there is a DragDropEnabled property to control this. If that does not work, handle the BeforeNodeDragStart event and cancel the drag.

[Edit: Added the following]

To prevent dragging a node under certain nodes and not others, handle the BeforeNodeDrop event and setting Cancel=true if the node being dragged cannot be added as a child to the destination node.

Comment: I've figured out how to enable/disable particular tree nodes from being dragged, but what I want is to declare that certain nodes can have children and others can't.

Comment: @wonea I have added more information to the answer. Does this help?

Comment: Yes, I do a type comparison.  A derive nodes for different type, say RSSNode : Node, and InboxNode : Node.  This is fine but it falls down as I can't reorder the nodes, so my only option seems to be disable the child drop somehow.